# Mocking Database call Asp.net MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, testing, mocking

How can I mock the database calls to make my application logic been tested without database?

Answer (score 2):

Use the [repository pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html) and mock it in your tests using a mocking framework such as [MoQ](http://code.google.com/p/moq/).

**Edit:** check out [this article](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2008/06/12/tdd-introduction-to-moq.aspx) by Stephen Walther on MoQ.

Comment: I agree about using the repository pattern (and, hence, will up-vote).  But, for as much as I like Moq, I don't mock my repositories with Moq. I think a hard-coded, mocked implementation, using the same interface as the "real" repository, is more flexible. But you're right that Repository is key.

Comment: The article moved, new url is here
http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2008/06/12/tdd-introduction-to-moq.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Repository pattern with a hardcoded implementation or use an XML file (my preference).

Answer (score 0):

```
procedure GetData (output arrayOfData)
  arrayOfData.record1.field1 = "dataA"
  arrayOfData.record1.field2 = "dataAB"
  arrayOfData.record2.field1 = "dataB"
  arrayOfData.record2.field2 = "dataBB"
  return arrayOfData)
end procedure
```

Then call GetData and use that chunck of data that you needed defined for your logic anyway.  Later, change GetData to really get data from the database.  Right now, just fake it, and assign it reasonable data by hand.